# How can be set a default proxy setting for all local users for SVN?

Tags: windows, svn, service, tortoisesvn, salt-stack

I'm trying to automate some SVN commands with Salt-Stack.
The target server is on a network with no access to the SVN server. In order to overcome this issue I'm using a proxy server.
I found that the settings I need to change are in %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers file.
This strategy works fine when it's manually done.
The issue is the the salt-stack minion (agent) is the one that is suppose to make this changes automatically, but unfortunately the minion (agent) is a windows service running as "Local System" logon, therefor the %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers is pointing to system32 and there are no Subversion\servers file.

Is it possible to set global proxy settings for SVN that is applied for all local users?

P.P. I'm using TortoiseSVN.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try creating `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers` i.e. `c:\windows\system32\Subversion\servers` with the proxy configuration in question? According to the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html), SVN should pick it up from there.

Comment: What Windows version are you using? Seems like for Windows 7, [the proper location would be `C:\ProgramData\Subversion\servers`](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/all-usersapplication-data/f3dffcde-7352-44dc-8b38-02aa90f09c32)...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help!
It turns out the place where I need to store the servers file is in "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Subversion"

Now it works fine now :)